# Issue with Redis Caching and Pagination Logic Causing Hanging Queries

Tags: caching, next.js, pagination, prisma, ioredis

**Introduction**

I am currently facing a puzzling issue with Redis caching and pagination logic in my NextJS application. The problem arises when I combine Redis caching (ioredis) with the skip filter in a query, causing the query execution to hang indefinitely. I have isolated the issue to the skip filter, and disabling Redis caching resolves the problem. However, I would like to leverage Redis caching for improved performance while maintaining the pagination functionality. I am seeking assistance to understand the underlying cause of this issue and find a solution.

**Problem Description**

In my application, I use Redis caching along with Prisma and a pagination mechanism to retrieve data efficiently. The pagination logic relies on the skip filter, which calculates the number of records to skip based on the limit and page values. However, when Redis caching is enabled, queries involving the skip filter tend to hang, making it impossible to retrieve the desired results.

**Relevant code**

src/lib/prismadb.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-var */
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import redis from 'services/redis'
import { createPrismaRedisCache } from 'prisma-redis-middleware'
import logger from 'services/logger'
import SiteSettings from 'config/settings'

// PrismaClient setup.
// See https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/connection-management
declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

const client = global.prisma ?? new PrismaClient()
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') global.prisma = client

// Setup redis caching.
if (redis != null) {
  redis.on('connect', () => {
    const cacheMiddleware: Prisma.Middleware = createPrismaRedisCache({
      ...(redis != null && {
        storage: {
          type: 'redis',
          options: {
            client: redis,
            invalidation: { referencesTTL: SiteSettings.DATABASE.CACHE_TTL }
          }
        }
      }),
      cacheTime: SiteSettings.DATABASE.CACHE_TTL,
      onHit: (key) => {
        const params = JSON.parse(key).params
        void logger?.info(`Cache hit for model ${params.model}`, { ...params })
      },
      onMiss: (key) => {
        const params = JSON.parse(key).params
        void logger?.info(`Cache miss for model ${params.model}`, { ...params })
      },
      onError: (error: any) => {
        void logger?.error('Cache error', {
          error: {
            message: error.message,
            stack: error.stack
          }
        })
      }
    })

    prisma?.$use(cacheMiddleware)
  })
}

export default client
```

src/utils/project.ts

```
export const getProjects = async (
  filter?: PaginationDataFilter,
  teamId?: string
): Promise<PaginationData<Project>> => {
  try {
    const result = await prisma.$transaction([
      prisma.project.count({
        where: {
          ...(teamId != null && { teamId }),
          ...(((filter?.search) != null) && {
            OR: [
              { name: { contains: filter?.search, mode: 'insensitive' } },
              { team: { name: { contains: filter?.search, mode: 'insensitive' } } }
            ]
          })
        }
      }),
      prisma.project.findMany({
        where: {
          ...(teamId != null && { teamId }),
          ...(((filter?.search) != null) && {
            OR: [
              { name: { contains: filter?.search, mode: 'insensitive' } },
              { team: { name: { contains: filter?.search, mode: 'insensitive' } } }
            ]
          })
        },
        ...(((filter?.limit) != null) ? { take: +filter?.limit } : {}),
        ...(((filter?.limit) != null) && ((filter?.page) != null)
          ? {
              take: +filter?.limit,
              skip: +filter?.limit * (+filter?.page - 1)
            }
          : {}),
        ...(((filter?.sort) != null) && { orderBy: { [filter?.sort.name]: filter?.sort.order } }),
        include: { searchhistory: true, writerhistory: true }
      })
    ])
    const response = {
      data: result[1],
      meta: {
        current_page: ((filter?.page) != null) ? filter?.page : 1,
        from: ((filter?.limit) != null) && ((filter?.page) != null) ? +filter?.limit * +filter?.page : 1,
        last_page: ((filter?.limit) != null) ? result[0] % +filter?.limit : 1,
        to: ((filter?.limit) != null) ? filter?.limit : result[0],
        total: result[0]
      }
    }
    utilLogger({ meta: { ...meta, function: 'getProjects' }, data: response })
    return response
  } catch (e: any) {
    utilLogger({ meta: { ...meta, function: 'getProjects' }, error: e })
    return {
      data: [],
      meta: {
        current_page: 1,
        from: 0,
        last_page: 1,
        to: 0,
        total: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Outcome**

When Redis caching is enabled, the pagination logic should work seamlessly, allowing the retrieval of paginated data without any hanging or delay issues. The skip filter should accurately calculate the number of records to skip based on the provided limit and page values.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken**

1. I verified that the Redis caching middleware is correctly integrated into my application and that the cache connection is established successfully.
2. I reviewed the configuration settings of the Redis caching middleware, including cache time, cache invalidation options, and the models included in caching.
3. I examined the code related to pagination, focusing on the skip filter, to ensure it is implemented correctly and accurately calculates the number of records to skip.
4. Commenting out this line fixes the issue, but pagination is broken:

```
skip: +filter?.limit * (+filter?.page - 1)
```

5. Also adding this to createPrismaRedisCache helps, but this disables caching altogether:

```
models: [
   { model: 'Project', excludeMethods: ['count', 'findMany'] }
],
```

6. Disabling Redis caching entirely eliminates the hanging issue but also removes the benefits of caching, negatively impacting performance.

**Request for Assistance**

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions regarding this issue. Specifically, I am seeking guidance on how to effectively combine Redis caching and pagination logic to avoid the hanging queries caused by the skip filter. Any help or advice would be invaluable in resolving this puzzling problem.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise.